# What happens to the chips in the middle if someone is disqualified?

Tags: rules

I was running a tournament where someone said something sexist to which I pulled them up on, I also told them if they say it again I will DQ them on the spot.

The rest of the night was tense but luckily nothing was said.  The next day I sent them a message stating that they were no longer welcome.

What got me thinking was what would have happened if they said something to get them disqualfied while they were in a hand and there were chips in the middle?
A) If it's a heads up situation what happens to the chips?  It's not really fair to give the chips to the opposing player if they don't have the winning hand.
B) What happens when there are more than 2 players?  Again, not really fair if the winner gets all the chips, especially if they didn't have the best hand.

Answer (score 2):

In a tournament, if someone is disqualified, his chips will remain at his seat and, because he cannot play, he shall be blinded out because he will be forced to put his blinds and antes when the SB and BB come to him (situation named **sitout**).

In a heads-up situation, I think the answer is obvious: the other guy wins.

Comment: What about the chips in the middle if they were DQ'd mid way through a hand?

Comment: I don't think this case is possible.

Comment: Agreed. Dq after the hand.

Comment: DQ'ing after a hand may not be an option, what if he then decides to throw more obscenities or simply walk away?

Comment: Shortly put, in a (serious) live game, either tournament or cash game, each player has allotted an amount of time to make a decision (let's say, a minute but I don't know the real value). If the time expires and he didn't make any decisions, he is considered sitout for the hand.